# Redirect with axios response in react

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-router, form-submit

I have a form Class Component, that uses Axios to submit to database. I want to wait for the Axios response so I can get the ID, then redirect using the ID in a route.

My problem is I keep getting

TypeError: this.props.navigate is not a function

Because useNavigate() can't be used in Class component. I tried using useHistory but it's deprecated and don't want to downgrade react.

```
    handleSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("SUBMITTED")
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('title',this.state.title);
        formData.append('description',this.state.description);
        formData.append('author',this.state.author);
        formData.append('hashtags',this.state.hashtags);
        formData.append('file',this.state.file);
        axios.post('http://localhost:8002/upload',formData,{})
        .then(res=>{
            this.setState({id:res.data.zineCreated._id})
            console.log(res.data.zineCreated._id)
            console.log(res)
            //history
            let path = '/viewmyzine/62e0b9d44d0be19bd9e84bd5';
            this.props.navigate(path); //not working

            // this.props.navigation.navigate('/viewmyzine/62e0b9d44'); //not working
        })

    }
```

Outside the Class component I have

```
function WithNavigate(props) {
    let navigate = useNavigate();
    return <ViewZine test="NAGIVATE" navigate={navigate} />
}
```

But it still doesn't work

Comment: Is the route a route on the same page, or a route to different page? In other words, do you expect the page to reload or to stay the same?

Comment: I want to move to a different page (from create magazine page > view magazine that I created page) :) Thank you so much I'm reading your other response now

Comment: Please include all relevant code you are working with and have an issue using. Where is `WithNavigate` rendered? What is `ViewZine`? See [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try rendering a [`<Navigate>`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/components/navigate) component only if you have an id state available. This is what the [docs](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/components/navigate) recommend.

Alternatively, you could call `document.location.assign(path)` (or `window.location.assign(path)`) if you wanted to [reload the page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/assign), instead of using react router to handle a virtual location...

However, I was able to get a simplified version of your example (without using the `Navigate` component) working:

```js
import {useNavigate, BrowserRouter, Route, Routes} from 'react-router-dom'
import {Component} from 'react'

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Demo</h1>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='b' element={<blockquote>(at b)</blockquote>}/>
        </Routes>
        <NavigateWrapper />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

function NavigateWrapper(props) {
  const navigate = useNavigate()

  return (<NavigateButton navigate={navigate} />)
}

class NavigateButton extends Component {
  render() {
    return <button onClick={event => this.callNavigate()}>call navigate</button>
  }

  callNavigate() {
    alert(this.props.navigate)
    this.props.navigate('b')
  }
}
```

(see code sandbox [example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/pensive-leftpad-yc0tr9?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark))

So it should be possible to pass navigate as a prop to a component element, and it should work. If this doesn't work, I would suspect that something is no longer rendered when the callback happens...

Comment: Thank you so much I got it to work because of you!! I used The <Navigate> component. I will try your other way too. Have a nice weekend!